# Comparação de strings Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou começando a me aventurar no mundo da programação web e estou tendo dificuldades com o seguinte assunto:
Estou criando uma página para troca de senha. Gostaria de que o meu código comparasse o login que o usuário está tentando alterar a senha, com o login que está atribuído na minha session, convertendo o login para minúsculas e então fazendo a comparação.

```
<script>
    function validar(){
        var login = formlogin.nlogin.value;
        var senha = formlogin.nsenha.value;
        var novasenha = formlogin.novasenha.value;
        var logado = "<?php echo $logado?>"

        if (login != logado.toLowerCase()){
            alert('Você não pode alterar a senha para este usuário.');
            formlogin.nlogin.focus;
            return false;
        }
        if (login == ''){
            alert('Preencha o campo de login');
            formlogin.nlogin.focus;
            return false;
        }
        if (senha == ''){
            alert('Preencha o campo de senha');
            formlogin.nsenha.focus;
            return false;
        }
         if (novasenha == ''){
            alert('Preencha o campo Nova senha');
            formlogin.novasenha.focus;
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Quando faço a comparação, mesmo com a string convertida para minúsculas, recebo a mensagem de que é impossível trocar o usuário.

Alguma dica?

Comment: Da onde saiu `formlogin`?

Comment: De onde surgiu essa sintaxe php no meio do js? `var logado = "<?php echo $logado?>"`

Comment: formlogin é o nome do formulário. $logado é a variável em php que contém o nome de usuário da $_session do PHP. Foi a maneira que encontrei de passar para o javascript o valor da variável da $_session.

Comment: você deveria fazer isso no **código server**, no seu caso em `php`, imagina a senha sendo exibida no `html` e fácil de qualquer um ver exibindo o código fonte da página?

Comment: eu coloquei no javascript para poder colocar um pop-up alertando... vou tentar reescrever o código usando só php.

Comment: É muito perigoso você fazer esta verificação em JavaScript. Hoje em dia, qualquer pessoa com conhecimento básico possa excluir suas verificações através da função "Inspecionar Elemento" do navegador. Como se trata de sessão, aconselho a fazer no seu script PHP.

Comment: Na sua verificação a var logado esta sendo passada para lowerCase enquanto a var login permanece sem a mesma conversão, tente colocar no seu if login.toLowerCase()

Answer (score -1):

Tenta pegar o valor dos inputs dessa forma:

```
var login = document.getElementById('nlogin').value;
```